# Sleeper train for Paris to Milan

Tags: trains, transportation, paris, milan

Are there any days that the sleeper trains from Paris to Milan does NOT run?

On [Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com/thello-train-from-paris-to-italy.htm#How_to_buy_tickets_for_Thello..._), the chart says it runs daily, but I'm not sure that truly means 365 days (Easter, Christmas even, New Years Eve, etc.). Does anyone know for sure? I can't check with the train website directly because booking doesn't open until 120 days prior to the desired date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, http://bahn.de/ is very good to find train connections, even if you are not traveling through Germany and/or cannot book that particular route through the site. Usually, you could therefore check in advance if the train runs on the days you are interested in but it won't help in this case.

The problem is not Thello's 120-day booking window (Christmas is already less than 120 days from now) but the bi-yearly timetable changes in European train networks. Timetables for the winter season (all the way to June) will be made officially available mid-October.

What you can still do in practice:

- Look in the past, the timetable for December 2012 is still available on bahn.de and could give you an idea of what to expect.
- Contact Thello directly, they probably already have an idea of their plans/slots for the coming season (if you do, please do come back and let us know!).

See also the [news for September 2013 on seat61.com](http://www.seat61.com/news.htm)

Comment: If you are referring to the EN223 train departing Paris 7:59PM for Venice, it runs daily except for November 30th. Note that as Annoyed pointed out, the current timetable is only valid until December 14th.